# TypeError: function() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, typeerror, python-turtle

Hi i am new to stack overflow and there maybe some issues on how i post this post.

So i wanted to make a turtle spawn a clone of it self at where the mouse clicks, but every time i run the code and click on the mouse it throws me the the error:
`TypeError: spawn() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

I tried going over the code again but couldn't find the problem, and i decided to ask here.
my code:

```
import turtle
import pyautogui
import tkinter as tk
import keyboard

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title('Planner')
wn.bgcolor('white')
wn.setup(width=800,height=800)
wn.tracer(0)

#Turtle 5x0.25:
block_5x025 = turtle.Turtle()
block_5x025.speed(0)
block_5x025.shape('square')
block_5x025.color('black')
block_5x025.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=0.25)
block_5x025.penup()

#Turtle 3x0.25
block_3x025 = turtle.Turtle()
block_3x025.speed(0)
block_3x025.shape('square')
block_3x025.color('black')
block_3x025.shapesize(stretch_wid=3, stretch_len=0.25)
block_3x025.penup()

def clear_screen():
    wn.clear()

def get_mouse_click_coor(x, y):
    turtle.onscreenclick(None)
    #block_5x025.goto(x,y)
    print(x, y)

def motion(event):
    x, y = event.x, event.y
    print('{}, {}'.format(x, y))
    block_5x025.goto(x-400,-y+400)
    block_3x025.goto(x-400,-y+400)

canvas = turtle.getcanvas()
canvas.bind('<Motion>', motion)

class Block:
    def __init__(self, size, thickness = 0.25, color = "black"):
        self.size = size
        self.thickmess = thickness
        self.color = color

    def spawn_block(self, block):
        i = 1
        for n in range(1):
            globals()["wall" + str(i)] = block.clone()
            globals()["wall" + str(i)].goto(block.xcor(),block.ycor())
            i += 1

class Wall_5x025(Block):
    def __init__(self, size = 5, thickness = 0.25, color = "black"):
        super().__init__(size, thickness, color)

    def spawn(self):
        super().spawn_block(block_5x025)

class Wall_3x025(Block):
    def __init__(self, size = 3, thickness = 0.25, color = "black"):
        super().__init__(size, thickness, color)

    def spawn(self):
        super().spawn_block(block_3x025)

def turn():
    block_5x025.right(90)
    block_3x025.right(90)

def switch():
    b3025 = 0
    b5025 = 1
    if keyboard.is_pressed('e'):
        b3025, b5025 = b5025, b3025

    if b3025 == 0:
        block_3x025.hideturtle()
    else:
        block_3x025.showturtle()

    if b5025 == 0:
        block_5x025.hideturtle()
    else:
        block_5x025.showturtle()

while True:
    wn.update()

    wn.listen()
    turtle.onscreenclick(get_mouse_click_coor)
    wn.onkeypress(turn, 'r')
    wn.onkeypress(clear_screen, 'c')
    turtle.onscreenclick(Wall_5x025.spawn)
    switch()
```

also i am sorry if something is not written correctly or is not understandable...

Comment: Can you tell the line number of which this occurs?

Comment: where is `spwan()` function in code given.

Comment: could you specify in which function is problem and Traceback if you have?

Comment: @SurajS i am sorry i accidently misspelled spawn

Comment: @Zviad, Arkilo yes, i will send the full error message.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "...\Python\Python37-32\lib\turtle.py", line 675, in eventfun
    fun(x, y)
TypeError: spawn() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there are problems with your code beyond the issue that brought you to SO.  For example, `while True:` is not what you want in an event-driven environment like turtle; your `clear_screen()` won't work as implemented (it destroys your `block_5x025` & `block_3x025` blocks; you don't need the `keyboard` module; you don't need `tracer()` and `update()`; you don't need to keep both example blocks in sync; etc.

Below is my rework and simplification of your code to do basically what you want:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

class Block(Turtle):
    def __init__(self, size, thickness=0.25, color="black"):
        super().__init__(shape='square', visible=False)

        self.shapesize(stretch_wid=size, stretch_len=thickness)
        self.color(color)
        self.penup()

class Wall_3x025(Block):
    def __init__(self, size=3, thickness=0.25, color="black"):
        super().__init__(size, thickness, color)

class Wall_5x025(Block):
    def __init__(self, size=5, thickness=0.25, color="black"):
        super().__init__(size, thickness, color)

# Turtle 3 x 0.25
block_3x025 = Wall_3x025()

# Turtle 5 x 0.25:
block_5x025 = Wall_5x025()

active_block = block_3x025

def switch():
    global active_block

    screen.onkeypress(None, 'e')  # disable handlers inside handler
    screen.onclick(None)

    if active_block == block_3x025:
        active_block = block_5x025
    else:
        active_block = block_3x025

    cursor.shape(active_block.shape())
    cursor.shapesize(*active_block.shapesize())
    cursor.color(*active_block.color())

    screen.onclick(spawn)  # reenable handlers
    screen.onkeypress(switch, 'e')

blocks = []

def spawn(x, y):
    screen.onclick(None)
    blocks.append(cursor.stamp())
    screen.onclick(spawn)

def motion(event):
    canvas.unbind('<Motion>')
    x, y = event.x, event.y
    cursor.goto(x - 400, 400 - y)
    canvas.bind('<Motion>', motion)

def turn():
    screen.onkeypress(None, 'r')
    cursor.right(90)
    screen.onkeypress(turn, 'r')

def clear_walls():
    screen.onkeypress(None, 'c')

    for block in blocks:
        cursor.clearstamp(block)

    screen.onkeypress(clear_walls, 'c')

screen = Screen()
screen.title('Planner')
screen.bgcolor('white')
screen.setup(width=800, height=800)

cursor = Turtle(shape=block_3x025.shape())
cursor.shapesize(*block_3x025.shapesize())
cursor.color(*block_3x025.color())
cursor.speed('fastest')
cursor.penup()

canvas = screen.getcanvas()
canvas.bind('<Motion>', motion)  # this event not exposed by turtle

screen.onkeypress(turn, 'r')
screen.onkeypress(switch, 'e')
screen.onkeypress(clear_walls, 'c')
screen.onclick(spawn)
screen.listen()

screen.mainloop()
```

It's based on making *stamps* instead of cloning turtles.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, but could i ask what do you mean by making stamps and why do you always set the  onclick or the onclickscreen as None first?

Comment: @Artelion, one of the things Python turtle can do is make impressions of the turtle itself ontotthe screen, aka *stamps*.  The key is to get the turtle cursor to look the way you want before you stamp it.  Stamps have *ids* that can be used later to remove the stamp.

Comment: @Artelion, I set the event handler function to `None` at the start of the event handler so that subsequent events that occur while the handler does what it does don't reinvoke it before it's finished.  Otherwise, this can lead to a faux recursion errors and/or other problems.

Answer (score 1):

Per the documentation, https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.onscreenclick, `turtle.onscreenclick` takes "a function with two arguments which will be called with the coordinates of the clicked point on the canvas" as it's argument. The spawn method you pass to `onscreenclick` only takes one argument, `self`. The spawn method should instead take a pair of coordinates.

Comment: oh ok, thank you very much i will try to change it